# Create a big list in R with loop

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a problem with this:
I need a create a list of matrices. Here is a Data Frame:

```
data=data.frame("Node"=c(1:5), posx=c(2,3,6,8,1), posy=c(1,1,4,7,8))
  Node posx posy
1    1    2    1
2    2    3    1
3    3    6    4
4    4    8    7
5    5    1    8
```

Now I want to create a list of matrices. With Loop. I want to create list of matrices like this:

```
l=list(l1,l2,l3,l4,l5)
```

where:

```
l1=cbind(c(2),c(1))
l2=cbind(c(3),c(1))
l3=cbind(c(6),c(4))
l4=cbind(c(8),c(7))
l5=cbind(c(1),c(8))
```

And here is my try:

```
for (i in 1:(data$Node) ) {
  l=list(cbind(c(data$posx[i]), (data$posy[i])))
}
```

Comment: I think what you wanted for the new question is `list2env(setNames(lapply(split(as.matrix(data[,-1]),row(data)[,1]), matrix, ncol=2), paste0('mat', 1:nrow(data))), envir=.GlobalEnv)` Then check `mat1`, `mat2`

Comment: Yes, many thanks it is! I apologize for the not very good question.

Comment: No problem, I got confused about what you really wanted.  But, I think it is better to have it in a list rather than as individual matrices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(data)), function(i) as.matrix(data[i,-1]))
```

Or

```
lapply(split(data[,-1],row(data)[,1]), as.matrix)
```

Or

```
lapply(split(as.matrix(data[,-1]),row(data)[,1]), matrix, ncol=2)
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,list(list(as.matrix(.SD))) , by=Node]$V1
```

Comment: Many thanks! It is working! And what in the case, if i have an extra column? Example: data=data.frame("Node"=c(1:5), posx=c(2,3,6,8,1), posy=c(1,1,4,7,8), rnd=c("A","B","C","D","E")) . But I want only numbers? (Without the last column?)

Comment: @sgtFury Try `lapply(split(data[,2:3], row(data)[,1]), as.matrix)`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `by`:

```
by(data[-1], data[1], as.matrix)
```

Comment: I will try it tomorow! Thank you for you replied!